# f2py with intelvem (Windows): Fortran functions get linked to kernel32.dll leading to ImportError

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, dll, fortran, f2py

When using f2py (Windows 7 64, Intel VS2008 C & Visual Fortran Composer XE 2011 compilers, Python 2.7, numpy 1.9.2) to convert FORTRAN90 source to a Python DLL, the f2py process completes without error, but the DLL will not `import` into Python, throwing the following error:

```
>>> import superdll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Using `ctypes` to import the .pyd file displays a more useful error:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.CDLL('superdll.pyd')
```

Prompts a popup windows stating:

```
"The procedure entry point for_getcmd_arg could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.DLL."
```

Using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), I have found that my Fortran procedures/functions are trying to be linked to `Kernel32.dll`, where they are obviously not present (see pic below).  These same Fortran procedures/functions are linked, correctly, to `libifcoremd.dll` (part of Visual Fortran Composer).

[image]

Any suggestions to fixing what appears to be an unnecessary linking to `kernel32.dll` using VS2008 linker with Visual Fortran compiler (ifort)?

Note: all of this works using Cygwin and RHEL with the same versions of Python & numpy, but using the GNU 4.4 equivalent compilers.

**EDIT**:  Added command line calls:

**f2py call:**

```
f2py.py -c --fcompiler=intelvem <list of .f90 files> -m superdll
```

**VS C compiler calls:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -I<path/to/source> -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tc<path/to>\superdllmodule.c /Fo<path/to>\superdllmodule.obj

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -I<path/to/source> -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tc<path/to>\fortranobject.c /Fo<path/to>\fortranobject.obj
```

**Fortran compiles**

```
(I can include this if needed)
```

**Linker call:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:initsuperdll <path/to/>superdllmodule.obj <path/to/>fortranobject.obj <list of .o files> <path/to/>superdll-f2pywrappers2.o /OUT:.\superdll.pyd /IMPLIB:<path/to/>superdll.lib /MANIFESTFILE:<path/to/>superdll.pyd.manifest
```

Comment: Is your vs2008 configured as discussed here to search fortran libraries?: [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/configuring-visual-studio-for-mixed-language-applications)

Comment: @Flash, were you able to solve this? I'm having the exact same issues.